# Passing input parameter from a config file in AWK command

Tags: unix, awk, substr

I am new to unix shell scripting.
I need to parse fixed length data file and convert to comma delimeter.
I manage to do this. By using code below:

```
awk '{
 one=substr($0,1,1)
 two=substr($0,2,10)
 three=substr($0,12,4)
 four=substr($0,16,2)
 rest=substr($0,18)
 printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", one, two, three, four, rest)
}' data.txt > out.txt
```

Data.txt:

```
k12582927001611USNA
k12582990001497INAS
k12583053001161LNEU
```

Output.txt:

```
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

The problem is I have a requirement to read the
column position from a config file.

My configfile (configfile.txt) as below:

```
one=substr($0,1,1)
two=substr($0,2,10)
three=substr($0,12,4)
four=substr($0,16,2)
rest=substr($0,18)
```

To meet the requirement, I have created script as below:

```
configparam=`cat configfile.txt`
awk '{
$configparam
printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", one, two, three, four, rest)
}' data.txt > out.txt
```

but its not working. Can anybody here show me the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: Does your config file REALLY contain statements like `one=substr($0,1,1)`? If so - why that instead of just `1 10 4 ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easiest way is to create file, which contains position start and no of chars like below, you don't have to write so many time `one=substr($0,start,n_char);`:

Input:

```
$ cat infile 
k12582927001611USNA
k12582990001497INAS
k12583053001161LNEU
```

Position file:

```
$ cat pos 
1,1
2,10
12,4
16,2
18
```

One-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{pos[++i,"s"]=$1;pos[i,"e"]=$2+0?$2:length;next}{for(j=1; j<=i; j++) printf("%s%s", substr($0,pos[j,"s"],pos[j,"e"]),j==i?ORS:OFS)}' pos infile 
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

Better Readable :

```
awk 'BEGIN{
            FS=OFS=","
     }
     FNR==NR{
            pos[++i,"s"]=$1;
            pos[i,"e"]=$2+0?$2:length;
            next
     }
     {
          for(j=1; j<=i; j++) 
             printf("%s%s", substr($0,pos[j,"s"],pos[j,"e"]),j==i?ORS:OFS)
     }' pos infile
```

Comment: another good solution! (Getting close to 10K!) Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Thank you so much, another 900+ to go

Comment: @AkshayHegde, you ROCK, I know you will get it done soon(10 k). My wishes are with you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its a very good solution. More dynamic. Thanks dude

Comment: @zimzim: you are welcome, one more thing you may not noticed, the order you give in position file, the column shifts accordingly, so it will be easy for you to swap columns

Answer (score 1):

I've reorganized it as

`cat cfg.awk`

```
{ 
   one=substr($0,1,1)
   two=substr($0,2,10)
   three=substr($0,12,4)
   four=substr($0,16,2)
   rest=substr($0,18)
}
```

`cat printer.awk`

```
{ printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", one, two, three, four, rest) }
```

run as

```
awk -f cfg.awk -f printer.awk data.txt
```

output

```
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

The only difference is that you need to add opening/closing `{ .. }` (curly braces) around your `var=substr` code.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Following awk may also help you in same.

```
awk '
function check(val, re){
  split(val, array,",");
  re=array[1] && array[2]?substr($0,array[1],array[2]):substr($0,array[1]);
  return re
}
FNR==NR{
  match($0,/\(.*\)/);
  a[FNR]=substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-5);
  count++;
  next}
{
for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
  val=val?val "," check(a[i]):check(a[i])
};
  print val;
  val=""
}
' Input_file_config   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
k,1258292700,1611,US,NA
k,1258299000,1497,IN,AS
k,1258305300,1161,LN,EU
```

Comment: I'd have to think about this one, but I'm sure you're right!